# Add resources to code snippet

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

The amazing Stack Snippet is intended for [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) and related libraries/frameworks. I love it.

But suppose you try to make an AJAX request, or an `ng-include` for instance. As the tool is right now, you can not do that.

I'd like to include custom additional resources such as partial HTML or JSON documents. Just extra text resources.

This would allow us to write better examples, even *complete answers* in many cases without needing external websites such as Plunker.

### Simple sample (in AngularJS):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])

.controller('ctrl', 
  function($scope, $http) {
     
    $scope.items = [ { 'name': 'Loading...' } ];
    
    // NOTE: the data.json here will not work on stack-snippet 
    
    $http.get('data.json').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.items = data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.items = [ { 'name': 'Error data.json does not exist.' } ];
    });

  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<ul ng-controller="ctrl" ng-app="app">
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
<!-- the partial.html here will not work, of course... --> 
<ng-inculde src="partial.html"></ng-include>
```

### Proposed Markup:

```
<!-- x-begin snippet: js hide: false -->
 // ...
<!-- file: data.json -->
[   
   { 'name': 'Alice' }, 
   { 'name': 'Bob' },
   { 'name': 'Carol' }
]

<!-- file: partial.html -->

<p>ngInclude works!</p>

<!-- x-end snippet -->
```

**Note:** I used Angular but this does not apply only to Angular + AJAX questions. This feature applies to any JavaScript sample that uses the `XMLHttpRequest` object or the Fetch API.

Comment: Can you provide an example, either something in this post or a post on SO, that would benefit from this feature?

Comment: This would be a nice feature although I can't find many use cases. If you already know the returned data then you don't really need to make the ajax request to get the data again. If you want to do something with the returned data you can also do it outside a success method.

Comment: @Spokey if the question is about the ajax request itself, or if it is about the promise, or whole the synchronization, then it is useful.

Comment: That's gonna be a pain in the butt to implement... I'm not sure the effort would outweigh the gain.